# How does Link2SD app run an application that is not in the default directory?

Tags: android

How does Link2SD run an application that is not in the default installation directory? I want to be able to move an application that is not in the directory where the APK files are normally installed, but move it to another directory, move the application from the folder `/data/data` to another folder on android storage such that I can run this app from my application.

I want my application to be responsible for installing the apk normally and then, move it from that installation directory to another directory while being able to run the application in this directory. The only application I know that has this capability is the Link2SD application that moves an application to the SD card and allows it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link2SD only moves App Data to Memory Card/External storage. Android System itself allows you to do so in App Settings.

Look at [App Install Location](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

Comment: But Link2SD I think has an option that allows you to move an entire application to the SD and be able to run from that place. Thank you